# Convert multidimensional climate numpy array to Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to convert a multidimensional climate data into the pandas data frame. The shape of my numpy array is `temperature.shape -> (365,100,200) -> ["time", "longitude", "latitude"]`. Then I would like to have the following columns in my pandas dataframe: `columns=["time", "lon", "lat", "temp"]`.

I tried this code:
`df = pd.DataFrame(temperature, columns=['time', 'lat', 'lon', 'temp'])`

I got this error:
*ValueError: Must pass 2-d input*

How can I solve it? I could not find any hint in suggested topics. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas is expects a 2D array where the columns and rows correspond to the final data frame.

It looks like you're trying to unravel the (365,100,200) array in 365*100*200=7,300,000 individual records.  This can be done by flattening the array if you have the values for each independent quantity along each access.
For example, unravelling a (3,4,5) shaped 3D array with X, Y and Z dimensions given by the lists/arrays `x_index`, `y_index`, `z_index`, rather than time, longitude, latitude and M replacing temperature:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

nx = 3
ny = 4
nz = 5

M = np.ndarray((nx,ny,nz))
for i in range(nx):
    for j in range(ny):
        for k in range(nz):
            M[i,j,k] = (i+j)*k
            
# constructed nx by ny by nz matrix from function f(x,y,z) = (x+y)*z
            
x_index = list(range(nx))
y_index = list(range(ny))
z_index = list(range(nz))

# Get arrays/list giving the values of x/y/z

X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x_index,y_index,z_index)

# Make (3,4,5) arrays of each independent variable

pd.DataFrame({"M=(X+Y)*Z":M.flatten(), "X":X.flatten(), "Y":Y.flatten(), "Z":Z.flatten()})

# Flatten the data and independent variables to make 3*4*5=60 individual records
```